# Ara there any Chernoff concentration inequalities for linear combination of binomial distirbutions?

Tags: probability

Given that $N_1,N_2...N_k$ are binomial distributions, $N_i\sim B(k_i,p_i)$, is there any  Chernoff bound for the sum $\sum_{i=1}^k a_i N_i$, which depends only on the expected values $k_i\cdot p_i$?

Comment: What dependency on $a_i$ do you expect?

Comment: Non assumtions.